# 2017 MBP screen flashes green or yellow when waking from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

Ive got a 2017 MBP 15". I have File Vault enabled.

When its been sleeping and I wake it, the screen flashes either bright green or yellow for about a second before going to the login screen. Is this something to be concerned about? The machine is still under warranty, but i dont want to take it to the Apple store unnecessarily.

Ive noticed this only happens after waking the machine from a deep sleep, if i close the lid and re-open it after about 20 mins it does not happen.

Im running OSX 10.13.6

Comment: I’d probably make time for a trip to the Apple store before the warranty is up if this happens reliably such that you can definitely demonstrate it to the tech when you get there. You also might consider phone support (in the US: 800-692-7753). They could possibly let you know if a trip is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1):

What version of macOS are you using? High Sierra + Metal did cause some issues. There is a Reddit thread about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/73nc9h/after_high_sierra_weird_colors_when_waking_up/

It is a software problem. Double check to see if the OS is updated.

Definitely visit the store if this persists.

Comment: Im running 10.13.6 (latest version of 10.13) I cant upgrade to 10.14 without certain software i need to run failing, so stuck on 10.13 for the moment. What is Metal ? i havnt heard of that before